# UrlDecode in razor dropdownlist is not decoding string

Tags: c#, razor

UrlDecode is not decoding strings in a razor drop down list.
Here is what I have tried:

I have tried using WebUtility.UrlDecode and HttpUtility.UrlDecode

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.questions, new SelectList(Model.questions, 
"id", WebUtility.UrlDecode("Answer")), null, new { @class = "data"})
```

String in drop down list such as "My%20House" not decoding to "My House"

Answer (score 2):

> You can use something like :
>
> `@Html.Raw(YourValue)`
>
> or
>
> `@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(YourValue));`